# i got a strange sentence watching a movie

Tags: grammar, meaning

> boy : Wait, but half the guys in this school are shorter than you are.
>
> girl : Hence my conundrum.
>
> boy : Oh, ho, ho. **I would love nothing more than to hence your conundrum.** All I'm saying is let your freak flag fly.

a conversation from a movie, 'tall girl'. and I've never seen a sentence structure like this in bold.

I don't understand why a verb don't used after 'more than to'. and one more.

so what is the meaning of this sentence?? please let me know!!

Comment: It should definitely be a verb after "more than to", so it seems unlikely that you heard the word **hence**. Might it have been **have** or **answer**?

Comment: I think it probably was *hence my conundrum*. The joke is that the boy doesn't know what this means, and so he takes it as a vaguely sexually suggestive invitation. This is a common type of (usually lame) joke.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comment from @legatrix is the start of the answer to your question.

The boy understands perfectly what the girl is saying. Thinking quickly he takes the opportunity to misconstrue it in order to turn it into  vaguely suggestive remark.

The "Oh, ho, ho" supports my interpretation. We could tell more from the tone of voice in a clip from the movie.

Answer (score 1):

It's not grammatically correct, but it's not meant to be so.

It's [nothing more than](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nothing-more-than) a witty remark or a chat-up line, or possibly a display of affection.

*Nothing more than* is fairly common and it means *just*, *only*, *nothing but*.

> A part of me would like nothing more than to take you to my bed.
>
> Every soldier in a situation like that faced a terrible choice. You want nothing more than to live another day, nothing more than to bug out.

The boy didn't understand what the girl was saying and interpreted it as something suggestive.

It's similar to

> Kiss me.
>
> I would love nothing more than to kiss you.

but less romantic and more vulgar.

A naughty exclamation "Oh, ho, ho" shows that the boy might be into her, or he has been fantasising about having sex (with her).